# Docker Jmeter No X11 DISPLAY variable was set

Tags: docker, jmeter

i've downloaded  from https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter/tree/master image of jmeter, imported in Docker and executed, error appeared in the container, No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

In Images of Docker Desktop tried without any env variables and the above error appeared or by adding DISPLAY with different values, 0.0, 99, 10 but did receive a different error An error occurred: Can't connect to X11 window server using '0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

The image's [documentation](https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter/tree/master#running) states:

> **Running**
>
> The Docker image will accept the same parameters as jmeter itself, **assuming you run JMeter non-GUI with -n.**
>
> There is a shorthand run.sh command. See test.sh for an example of how to call run.sh.

So you're supposed to be [running your existing JMeter .jmx test plan in non-GUI mode.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)

If you want to see JMeter GUI in Docker you will need to install [X.org server](https://www.x.org/wiki/) and some form of a [VNC server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).

Comment: run of ./build.sh but received an error

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk update \t&& apk upgrade \t&& apk add ca-certificates \t&& update-ca-certificates \t&& apk add --update openjdk8-jre tzdata curl unzip bash \t&& apk add --no-cache nss \t&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \t&& mkdir -p /tmp/dependencies \t&& curl -L --silent ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} > /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz \t&& mkdir -p /opt \t&& tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt \t&& rm -rf /tmp/dependencies" did not complete successfully: exit code: 60.

Comment: The objective is to run a jmx script stored on my local Windows11 machine using jmeter installed on a Docker.